# Cloudzoom conflicts with fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox-2

I am trying to get fancybox to work with cloudzoom since last three days but I got no success still. The problem is that once I click on the image the fancybox popus up and I am able to navigate through the next/prev button however when I close the fancybox and get back to the images, the images are gone. I just end up with empty space. if I remove the cloudzoom class then everything works fine.

Can someone just apply fancybox to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuHuZ/69/) please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
width : 1100,
 height : 500,
  fitToView : true,
 autoSize : false,
 padding: [20, 20, 20, 20],
 });
 });
</script>
<a href="image/big.png" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="small.jpg" class="cloudzoom"></a>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DP6Ba/

Comment: @JFK fanybox isn't working.

Comment: click the area beside the photo

Comment: Okay now I got it thanks. But can you make it to work right on the image please?